# Manga with a boy saving a girl from monster attacks by playing music, is accompanied by a fairy

Tags: story-identification, manga

All I know about it is this:

- A young girl was roller skating and attacked by a monster.
- She was held captive then saved by a boy who helped by playing music who transformed and managed to defeat the monster.
- A couple of pages later it happened again this time at an ice rink and once again she got caught and saved by the same boy who played music on a piano and he's accompanied by a fairy I believe.
- I don't know exactly what happened next but all I know was at the end the girl, the boy, and the fairy saw a entity and the fairy said "that's a demigod" or something.

Comment: When did you read this, was it an older publication? Can you say anything about the art style?

Comment: Well I read back in high school like around 2005 or 2006 I was in my senior year when I read this fyi I was what's the word it's not work or anything more like helping out thing when I have the time I look around only to see a few mangas at the time it was with the first volume of sgt. Frog (I don't know the year the manga I'm looking for is I didn't even check if I did I don't remember). As for the art style well I do know it's not sailor moon art style

Comment: The art style look like this  Dream Saga Manga

Comment: Also posted at https://www.reddit.com/r/manga/comments/je6cpm/name_of_manga/ in case they come up with an answer there.

Comment: The one at reddit is mine is there a website where I can look up a manga of what I'm describing cause no matter where I look someone or something just don't give me the answer I seek it sucks